# iPhone Ajax AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax

I am using AJAX AutoCompleteExtender on a textbox. I have it all working successfully on all browsers except when running on an iPhone. On the iPhone the extender shows up but when I click one of the list items the extender disappears and the textbox is not populated. I think this is because iPhones don't raise click events.

The question is why does clicking in the AutocompleteExtender not populate the textbox on an iPhone? It works in every other browser including android phones.

I found a post saying raise click events don't work on the iPhone. Their suggestion was to add the below style. But didn't seem to make any difference.

```
<style type="text/css>
    .completionList {
        cursor: pointer:
    }
</style>

<div class="input-group col-sm-8">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchHandle" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <asp:Button ID="btn_quickSearch" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Quick Add" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btn_quickSearch_Click" />
  </span>  
</div>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="2"
CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="2"
TargetControlID="txtSearchHandle" OnClientPopulated="QuickCarline_Populated"
ID="AutoCompleteExtender2" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "true" UseContextKey="True"
BehaviorId="AutoEx" CompletionListCssClass="completionList"> 
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: 1. Looks like your code block is too much idented

2. There is no actual question in your question. What have you tried to do? Have you tried to debug problem somehow?

Comment: Sorry about the code. The question is why does clicking in the AutocompleteExtender not populate the textbox on an iPhone? It works in every other browser including android phones.

Comment: Please, add this question to body of question for community to easily find this. Also any supporting information will be helpful if that's available. For example, did you try to debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was very disappointing. It doesn't seem like AJAX AutoCompleteExtender supports iOS. I have not found anywhere on AjaxToolkit.net them stating that this functionality will not work on iPhone|iPad etc. I finally moved on the jqueryUI to get the same/better functionality.